# Exit if statement and continue with next code

Tags: javascript

So I got this if statement that checks whether media file is type of image. Whether is true, how can I exit this if statement and continue to next lines of codes where is `await...` ?

When I added `: continue` I am getting error `expression expected`.

```js
   if(mediaValue.value == 'image') {
          const validateMedia = mediaFile.value.files[0].type.indexOf("image/") > -1

          return validateMedia == false ? showToast("notImageFile", "error") : continue;
        }
        await createData(
          route.params.shopid,
          route.params.id,
          params
        );
```

Comment: Ask your preferred search provider what the `return` keyword does.

Comment: since that statement is at the end of the if statement it will just do nothing since the if statement will end automatically as far as I can see. otherwise you cannot really "continue" or "break" out of an if statement.

Comment: If `mediaValue.value == 'image'` then you will definitely have trouble with accessing `mediaFile.value.files[0]`. Since it's like doing `'image'.files[0]`

Comment: As for your question, "exit this if statement" is a non-starter. You don't need to exit anything. If you want a certain command to only run when a condition is true, you put the command inside an if block, period. It's not more complex than that. There's no need to exit, continue or return. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Control_flow_and_error_handling#conditional_statements (`continue` is used inside *loops* to skip the rest of the current iteration and proceed with the next)

Answer (score 1):

You don't `return` from an `if`. If you want it not to show the toast popup in a certain situation then simply add another `if` so the code will skip that command when the condition isn't met. For example

```
if (validateMedia == false) showToast("notImageFile", "error");
```

After that the code will exit the `if` block naturally and continue with the next command.

P.S. If you want the processing to pause when the toast popup shows that's a slightly separate question...

Answer (score 0):

shouldn't this normally work?

```
      if(mediaValue.value == 'image') {
              const validateMedia = mediaFile.value.files[0].type.indexOf("image/") > -1
    // if validate media is false then it will return, if not then it will not return
              if( validateMedia == false)
              showToast("notImageFile", "error");
            }
            await createData(
              route.params.shopid,
              route.params.id,
              params
            );
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't return in the if statement. That'll solve your problem. When you return, you return from the function and no more execution ( The async call) will happen.